# txt file into array with delimiters in php

Tags: php, arrays, file, text, split

My `ips.txt` file contains the following content:

```
radie1230: 116.79.254.131
Y_O_L_O: 122.149.157.42
midgetman63: 121.121.14.101, 124.112.115.69, 114.182.51.1, 114.118.55.131, 111.21.22.156
kypero: 121.211.61.118, 117.117.117.46, 121.214.109.247, 111.219.37.75
lythorous: 111.161.225.214, 12.111.184.71, 1.112.201.113, 11.137.214.184, 1.115.21.117, 12.115.241.212, 11.117.116.217
```

This list contains usernames on the left, separated by `:` from IPs on the right. IPs are separated by `,`.

What would be an implementation to create the following output?

```
Array (
    [midgetman63] => Array
        (
            [0] => 121.121.14.101
            [1] => 124.112.115.69
            [2] => 114.182.51.1
            [3] => 114.118.55.131
            [4] => 111.21.22.156
        )
)
```

Comment: Anything you tried? Just something you can start by trying. Read the file line by line, explode each line with the `:` delimiter, then use the resulting array's first index as key, e.g. `midgetman63`, and explode the second index (being 1) with the `,` delimiter .. and you'r almost done ..

Comment: You could just find the line the text you are searching for is on, then $d = explode(':', $thatdata); $s = explode(',', $d); foreach $s as $i { array_push($output, $i); }

Comment: Yes I have tried bit did not get very far, ended up with blank arrays. But now I am using Gonzalo Bahamondez's method below, it is working great. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$dataFromFile = file('ips.txt');
$dataFromFile = array_map('trim', $dataFromFile);
$result = array();
foreach ($dataFromFile as $line) {
    list($user, $ips) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $arrayOfIPs = explode(',', $ips);
    $result[trim($user)] = array_map('trim', $arrayOfIPs);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Or yea thats a much better answer than mine

Comment: I am just thinking, shouldn't you change `explode(':', $line);` to `explode(':', $line, 2);`, so that IPv6 IPs will still work?

Comment: I am using Gonzalo Bahamondez's method below, it is working great. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont have spaces at the end of the textfile, this should be work.
good luck.

```
$text = file_get_contents("ipsontext.txt");
$array = explode("\n",$text);
$finally_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $this_key = explode(":",$value);
  $this_values = explode(",",$this_key[1]);
   foreach($this_values as $tv) {
       $finally_array[$this_key[0]][] = $tv;
     }  
 }
 var_dump($finally_array);
```

Comment: No problem, but i not read the mkjasinski's answer before of do my answer , her way is faster and 2 lines of code shorter. :) i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
<?php
$output = array();
$search = 'something';
$lines = file('file.txt');
foreach($lines as $line) {
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
    $d = explode(':', $line); 
    $s = explode(',', $d[1]); 
    foreach $s as $i { array_push($output, $i); }
  }
}

print_r($output);

?>
```

Comment: I am using Gonzalo Bahamondez's method below, it is working great. Thank you for your help though.